# developing a JQUERY plugin in a project built by webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack, plugins

im developing a jquery plugin in a project built by webpack. Regular wrapper for JQ plugin looks like this:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.pluginName = function(config) {
        const options = $.extend({
            option1: 'true',
            option2: 'true',
        }, config);

        return this.each( function() {
            // some code
        });
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

but to make it work with webpack i need to add before

```
(function(factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd && define.amd.jQuery) {
        // AMD. Register as anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        // CommonJS Module
        factory(require("jquery"));
    } else {
        // Browser globals.
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me please, what it actually do? And do i really need all this code?

Comment: That's not a lot of code.

Comment: let me understand what this magic trick dose, is that without it the JQ plugin will not work